# box ploting timeseries with pandas and matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a timeseries dataframe and I want to plot it using box plot type. Furthermore I want to group the data by days.

This is what I did,

```
groups = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))
data = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x[1].values) for x in groups], axis=1))

data.boxplot(figsize=(20,5))
plt.show()
```

This is the result,

[image]

Why I have lost the dates in X axis? Can achieve my goal in a easier way? I feel my code is not pythonic.

In addition I did the code below  too, but this stacks the days of different months.

```
sns.boxplot(x=d1.index.day, y=d1['Temperature'])
```

An example of my dataframe:

```
                       Temp
2019/01/01 00:00:00    25.3
2019/01/01 00:30:00    22.0
2019/01/01 01:00:00    22.1
2019/01/01 01:30:00    28.1
2019/01/01 02:00:00    26.8
2019/01/01 02:30:00    25.3
...
2019/01/02 00:00:00    20.2
2019/01/02 00:30:00    27.0
2019/01/02 01:00:00    27.5
2019/01/02 01:30:00    28.1
2019/01/02 02:00:00    28.8
2019/01/02 02:30:00    26.3
...
2019/02/10 23:30:00    21.6
```

Thank you!

Comment: Would you like to add a sample of grouped data to your question?

Comment: Sorry! Done! @r-beginners

Comment: Given the sample data: (1) `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` (2) `df['Day'] = df.index.day` (3) `sns.boxplot(data=df, x='Day', y='Temp')`